# Files have become unreadbale post git lfs migrate import, how to undo

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I did the following on my repository and now all the files have been replaced by statements like these(I have replaced the value in the second line with *s):

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:8*****************************************93
size 1003203
```

lfs commands run:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.xyz"
git lfs migrate import
```

Now all files including the xyz files are unreadable. How can I possibly undo these ?

Comment: Could you explain in more details what leads you to say "files are unreadable" ? does `cat file.xyz` print gibberish ? opening them in a regular editor ? trying to unzip them ? ...

Comment: Does `git lfs checkout` fix your problem?

Comment: @LeGEC the first code block is what my files look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import` changes all the files to their SHA keys. Running the following helped my case:

```
git lfs migrate export --include "*"
```

I used `--include "*"` here since I had run `migrate export` without an include flag and all the files were added to `.gitattributes`. In case of exclusive files being unreadable, do the following:

```
git lfs migrate export --include "filepath/filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`git lfs checkout`

followed by

`git lfs fetch`

Solution from [Retrieve original files after a git clone with git lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830343/retrieve-original-files-after-a-git-clone-with-git-lfs)