# Retrieve original files after a git clone with git lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am a bit confused. I back up a project with Github.com. Because my files are too large to store them on Github.com, I am using `git large file storage`. Now I changed to a new computer, and performed a `git clone` on the repository stored remotly on Github.com. I also installed `git lfs` with `brew` and did a `git lfs install` in the just cloned repository. However, my large files are still "pointer files". When I run my project,it says, these files are missing.

I did a

```
git lfs fetch --all
```

which downloaded something. But where is it?
How do I retrieve the files I backed up with `git lfs` after moving to a completly new computer with a fresh setup?

Comment: Depending on your Git and Git-LFS versions, you might want to use `git lfs clone`, which sets everything up. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48392440/1256452 (which goes into some detail about exactly what is different, which versions of Git and Git-LFS talk with each other, etc).

Comment: In your particular case, you probably have modern versions of everything and don't need to use `git lfs clone`—but you installed Git and Git-LFS in the "wrong order" such that the clone had already happened before you got Git-LFS installed. By running `git lfs clone` you would have seen that Git-LFS had not yet been installed. Of course `git lfs clone` is now deprecated, which is ... kind of annoying, really. Well, so it goes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
# Fetch all the LFS files from the remote
git lfs fetch

# Replace the pointer files to the actual files
git lfs checkout
```

Now you should see that the pointer files are replaced by the original files.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to run them the other way around, first fetch then checkout.